# dynamic form in jsp

Tags: jsp

I built a dynamic table in JSP using JavaScript. In that scenario when I click on "add more" link it adds rows to the table. But I'm unable to capture and pass those values to the database using java. How can I do that using javaScript?

Here I've attached the javaScript I used to add rows

```
function addRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell0.innerHTML=rowCount ;
        var cell1= row.insertCell(1);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        cell1.appendChild(element1);
           element1.name="description"+rowCount;
           element1.align = "center";
           element1.size=30;

        var cell2= row.insertCell(2);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        cell2.appendChild(element2);
           element2.name="required"+rowCount;
           element2.align= "center";
           element2.size=5;

        var cell3= row.insertCell(3);
        var element3 = document.createElement("input");
        cell3.appendChild(element3);
           element3.name="floor"+rowCount;
           element3.align= "center";
           element3.size=20;
```

Comment: Same way as a non-dynamic form; they're in the request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a submit action of some type that reinvokes the doPost Method on the servlet/controller.  You have to pass the data back down through the controller to the entity bean that way.

Add a submit button, in the servlet read the data from the fields and then send it down the stack to the Database